# Singly Linked-List (How to properly remove/free an entity?)

Tags: c, winapi, singly-linked-list

**Background**

I have the following code

```
VOID FD_Remove(FDescs List, PVOID FileDesc) {
    while (List) {
        if (List->Sock == FileDesc) {
            List->Next = (FDescs) LocalAlloc(sizeof(Network::FDesc));
            if (List->Next != ERROR) {
                FDescs Element = List->Next;

                List->Sock = List->Next->Sock;
                List->Host = List->Next->Host;
                List->Path = List->Next->Path;

                List->Next = Element->Next;
                LocalFree(Element);
            }
        } List = List->Next;
    }
}
```

**Notes**

Basically, when I am creating a new entry in the linked list. I will allocate a new memory block of the given structure size and set it to the end of the list, finding a block the same way as I do in this `_Remove` function.

However, when I am trying to remove an entity. I free the entity from the list as seen above, and set the current entity to the next entry in the list. The problem is, it appears that the `LocalFree` call doesn't actual set the allocated memory back to an unallocated block of memory. When I look at the linked-list the current entity simply has all of its entries set to `NULL (0)`.

Assume the `FileDesc` that I am passing to `FD_Remove` is the last entry of the list.

`FD_Remove(FDescList, 0x00000005);`

So we can assume that the memory that has the `0x00000005` entity is now freed.

Now I call `FD_Add(FDescList, FileDesc, 'whatever');`

I would only assume that these values would appear in the previously freed entity in the Linked-list.

**Problem**

The problem is that entity is set to `NULL` instead of freed memory, and the function adds the `FileDesc` and 'whatever' data to the entity after the `NULL` memory block instead of inside of it.

**Question**

What am I doing wrong in my `FD_Remove` function that is causing this, and how can I improve my function to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing an element from a linked list simply involves updating the surrounding element pointers to the element being removed, and then freeing the element.  You don't need to allocate or copy anything.

Try this instead:

```
VOID FD_Remove(FDescs List, PVOID FileDesc) {
    FDescs Previous = NULL;
    while (List) {
        if (List->FDesc == FileDesc) {
            if (Previous)
                Previous->Next = List->Next;
            LocalFree(List);
            return;
        }
        Previous = List;
        List = List->Next;
    }
}

FD_Remove(FDescList, (PVOID)0x00000005);
```

But, watch out if the element being removed is the `head` of your linked list.  If so, you need to update that pointer too, which the above function can't do directly.  You would have to do something more like this instead:

```
VOID FD_Remove(FDescs *List, PVOID FileDesc) {
    if (!List) return;
    FDescs Element = *List, Previous = NULL;
    while (Element) {
        if (Element->FDesc == FileDesc) {
            if (*List == Element)
                *List = Element->Next;
            if (Previous)
                Previous->Next = Element->Next;
            LocalFree(Element);
            return;
        }
        Previous = Element;
        Element = Element->Next;
    }
}

FD_Remove(&FDescList, (PVOID)0x00000005);
```